# Return Status 1 for Assigning Heredoc to Variable through a function

Tags: bash, shell, variable-assignment

This is one way to assign the contents of a here document to a variable. However, its execution will return a status of 1 without stating a reason.

```
#! /bin/bash
# set -e -x

# This implementation returns 1
define(){ IFS='\n'; read -r -d '' ${1}; }
define thedoc <<'EOF'
Here is my here doc.
There was an ASCII banana here too,
but `read` would just it concatenate to mush.
EOF
# The here document will print with the following when `set -e` in not invoked.
echo $thedoc
```

Everything checks out by inspection and even execution provided that `set -e` is turned off. This is not exclusive to the Banana above but any here doc built by `define()` above. From where does that error arise?

Comment: I'm not sure what it means, but when I run your code, all the 'n's are replaced with spaces in the value of `thedoc`.

Comment: That behavior is expected. The banana was perhaps a bad choice. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a null string as the delimiter for `read` it essentially never sees the delimiter and encounters end-of-file so it sets the return status to 1. You can use a `while read` loop to avoid that.

From the [Bash Reference Manual](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#IDX103):

> The return code is zero, unless end-of-file is encountered, `read` times out (in which case the return code is greater than 128), or an invalid file descriptor is supplied as the argument to '`-u`'.

Also, don't use `-e`. Use explicit error handling. See [BashFAQ/105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)

Additionally, in order to preserve spaces, tabs and newlines and not "concatenate to mush" you must quote the variable that you `echo`.